# Isolate click listener in overlapping row and button

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table as below: one column shows text, the other column contains buttons.
I need to implement two different actions: one when the row itself is clicked, one when the button is clicked.

But in the code below, I cannot isolate the two events when I click the buttons: meaning, both actions are executed since the row is also considered as "clicked". How do I isolate the two events? I have to use `appendChild` as the button is created dynamically in my actual code. Thanks.

```js
var r1cell2 = document.getElementById('r1cell2');
var r1c2Button = document.createElement("button")
r1c2Button.innerHTML = "R1C2"
r1cell2.appendChild(r1c2Button)

let r1 = document.getElementById("r1")
r1.addEventListener("click", () => {
  alert("R1 clicked")
})

r1c2Button.addEventListener("click", () => {
  alert("R1C2 Button clicked")
})
```

```html
<table id="tableId">
  <tr id="r1">
    <td id="r1cell1">Cell R1C1</td>
    <td id="r1cell2"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="r2">
    <td id="r2cell1">Cell R2C1</td>
    <td id="r2cell2"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Add [event.stopPropagation()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) to your button click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`event.stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) to contain event handling at button-level.

```js
var r1cell2 = document.getElementById('r1cell2');
var r1c2Button = document.createElement("button")
r1c2Button.innerHTML = "R1C2"
r1cell2.appendChild(r1c2Button)

let r1 = document.getElementById("r1")
r1.addEventListener("click", () => {
  console.log("R1 clicked")
})

r1c2Button.addEventListener("click", (e) => {

  e.stopPropagation();
  // ^^^^^ Here you can stop event being passed to upper level event listener
  
  console.log("R1C2 Button clicked")
})
```

```html
<table id="tableId">
  <tr id="r1">
    <td id="r1cell1">Cell R1C1</td>
    <td id="r1cell2"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="r2">
    <td id="r2cell1">Cell R2C1</td>
    <td id="r2cell2"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

You COULD add stopPropagation but instead I suggest you delegate proper

I normally add the event listener to the nearest static container. Here I made that the TBODY

```js
var r1cell2 = document.getElementById('r1cell2');
var r1c2Button = document.createElement("button")
r1c2Button.innerHTML = "R1C2"
r1cell2.appendChild(r1c2Button)

document.getElementById("tableId").addEventListener("click",function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.tagName==="BUTTON") {
     console.log(tgt.textContent," Button clicked")
  }
  else {
     console.log(tgt.closest("tr").id," row clicked")
  }
})
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody id="tableId">
    <tr id="r1">
      <td id="r1cell1">Cell R1C1</td>
      <td id="r1cell2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="r2">
      <td id="r2cell1">Cell R2C1</td>
      <td id="r2cell2"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

If you have more than one table you can move the event listener further out

Here I add it to the DIV - note I had to change the IDs to make sure they were unique

```js
var t1r1cell2 = document.getElementById('t1r1cell2');
var t1r1c2Button = document.createElement("button")
t1r1c2Button.innerHTML = "R1C2"
t1r1cell2.appendChild(t1r1c2Button)

document.getElementById("tableDiv").addEventListener("click",function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.tagName==="BUTTON") {
     console.log(tgt.textContent," Button clicked")
  }
  else {
     console.log(tgt.closest("tr").id," row clicked")
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="tableDiv">
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="t1r1">
      <td id="t1r1cell1">Cell R1C1</td>
      <td id="t1r1cell2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="t1r2">
      <td id="t1r2cell1">Cell R2C1</td>
      <td id="t1r2cell2"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<hr/>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="t2r1">
      <td id="t2r1cell1">Cell R1C1</td>
      <td id="t2r1cell2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="t2r2">
      <td id="t2r2cell1">Cell R2C1</td>
      <td id="t2r2cell2"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Can the eventlistener be added to anything that is parent/grandparent to the button here? Can it be the row itself? Or something that is parent to the table?

Comment: I always add it to the nearest static container. I made that the TBODY here. It can be document if you want this to work across several tables or a div that has more than one table in it

Comment: See update with two tables and a container DIV